# How can I synchronise the playback of several ogg files in Java?

Tags: java, ogg, vorbis

I have a song that has the different tracks in separate ogg files. I can play these ogg files together using Vorbis SPI to get the complete song. However I'm doing this by playing each ogg in a separate thread and I have no protection against the playback of each ogg file getting out of sync.

How would you go about ensuring they stay in sync. Ideally all tracks would pause if there was a delay reading any.

Once I've got this working I'll also be wanting to sync with graphics being displayed on screen.

I feel like what I need is some sort of time/location record so I know how far through each of the ogg playbacks have got to. I could then delay other threads until everything is back in sync.

I'm in early days so I'm happy to consider alternative playback libraries.

EDIT :

Following JimmyB's advice I'm now able to read into 4 byte buffers. I then add the buffers together using the following code :

```
for (int i = 0; i < byteLength; i++) {
    data[0][i] = data[0][i];
    for (int j = 1; j < numInputs; j++) {
        data[0][i] += data[j][i];
    }
}
```

This does work, but the output is distorted. I suspect clipping is occuring. How can I combine the sound bytes without this effect?

EDIT 2:
Dividing the byte by the number of inputs stops the clipping, but greatly reduces the quality of the playback.

EDIT 3:
I think I'm also losing sync between the tracks. My read method looks like :

```
// return true if there is more to come
private boolean fillBuffer(AudioInputStream audioInputStream, byte[] soundBytes) throws IOException {
    byte empty = 0;
    int offset = 0;
    while (offset != soundBytes.length) {
        int bytesRead;
        try {
            bytesRead = audioInputStream.read(soundBytes, offset, soundBytes.length - offset);

            offset += bytesRead;
            if (bytesRead == -1) {
                Arrays.fill(soundBytes, offset, soundBytes.length, empty);
                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            LOGGER.info("Boom");
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

It seems like the relationship between bytes read and time may not be linear? Perhaps that's in my head though.

Comment: You could decode one block of all tracks and then do the mixing of the decoded audio yourself before passing the guaranteed-in-sync audio to the soundcard. Then repeat. Use double buffering to avoid gaps in playback.

Comment: Appreciate the advice Jimmy, but I'm an absolute novice at handling audio in Java. Can you point me anywhere that might help me work out how to do what you've suggested?

Comment: Have a look at the first example at http://www.javazoom.net/vorbisspi/documents.html. The `rawplay` method reads (up to) 4kb of audio data from the (Ogg) AudioInputStream, then passes that data to the SourceDataLine for playback. Between those two steps is the point where you can intercept. You get a chunk of decoded audio of all channels, mix them all together into one block of audio data as you require, and then pass that single block to the SourceDataLine.

Comment: Getting closer. Any ideas on the clipping issue?

Comment: Notice that the stream provides individual *bytes*; a single *sample* may consist of more than one byte depending on the AudioFormat. You may have to convert two bytes to one 16 bit sample value before mixing those values.

Comment: Make sure all your input streams yield the same AudioFormat, esp. the same sample rate.